# The quickest search in 2d array for values greater than 0

Tags: python, performance, loops, dataframe, time

Here is my code:

```
    if frame is not None: self.x, self.y = np.where(frame > 0)
```

basically its searching values greater than 0 but its takes like forever and i need it to do it at least 10 times a sec for array 480x640. If it helps it always is only a few of this points. I am attaching my whole class maybe someone will improve it: (here is after edit)

```
import numpy as np


class Rect:
def __init__(self):
    self.rect = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]
    self.draw = False
    self.x = []
    self.y = []

def count_rect(self):
    self.rect[0] = (self.y[0], self.x[0])
    element, index = max(list(zip(self.y, range(len(self.y)))))
    self.rect[1] = (element + 20, self.x[index] + 150)
    self.draw = True

def points(self, frame):
    if frame is not None: self.x, self.y = np.where(frame > 0)
    if len(self.x) != 0 and len(self.y) != 0: self.count_rect()
    else: self.draw = False
```

idealy function np.where() should stop on first result, then go from the end and do the same

Comment: Are you computing this several times a second for the same frame, or for different frames? I ask in order to determine where to cache.

Comment: without caching, it's almost twice as fast (for me using timeit) if I just keep running min/max values, instead of putting everything in a list, then calling min/max afterwards.

Comment: its for examinating where to draw rectangle for moving objects from live feed, so for different frames, i have the working code now but the problem is to do it faster, check after edit

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete to me - where is the class even instantiated or used? Where are any frames read from any camera or simulation?

Comment: If you don't answer questions, no-one can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the where function?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

It returns you an index with the x,y coordinates with the points that satisfy your conditions. ex:

```
import numpy as np

#being A  your NxM array

index = np.where(A > o)
```

Comment: yep i'm getting there, thanks it;s close but i think i need some thing faster